# C# Charting zoom problem with DataTime for X axis

Tags: c#, datetime, zooming, charts

using the MS Charting for .NET, I am trying to zoom into the chart which I have created.

This works fine on the Y axis (type = float) and on the X axis if type = int, but when I have DateTime values on the X axis, scrolling does not behave as it should on this axis.

Vertically, everything still behaves properly, but while I can zoom into the X axis, I cannot drag the sliding bar to move where I am zoomed into. However, I can click either side and it will jump.

Does anyone know how to fix this and make it behave like it does with float values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your data, try setting the chart area's `CursorX.IntervalType` property to something other than Auto.

You may run into a similar issue when trying to use the small scroll arrows of the scroll bar once you are zoomed in. To fix that you can try to set the chart area's `AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSizeType` property to the same thing as the `CursorX.IntervalType`.

For example, if you have a chart with data that is reported every 30 seconds you can use the following settings:

```
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval = 0.5D;

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 0.5D;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but still not working. However, I had not come across the ScaleView, so will have a dig around and see if that provides me with any hints.

Comment: Very first helped: setting it to minutes worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and these settings solve it for me:

```
        _chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
        _chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        _chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
        _chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval = 1D;

        _chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
        _chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 1D;
        _chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

        _chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.MinSizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
        _chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.MinSize = 1D;

        _chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
        _chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize = 1D;
```

Especially the last two lines did the job.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
```